# Scrapy KeyError in Linux Server but not on Windows

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, scrapy

My Scrapy works just fine on my local machine, Windows. Then I try to run it on my AWS Linux server, but I got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run<spider_name>.py", line 12, in <module>
    spider_name).split())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 162, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 51, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: <spider_name>'
```

Why is that? How can I run it on my Linux Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly solved and I confused myself.

I solve it by updating all the requirements using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. I added Scrapy Splash to the requirement and I forgot to install it.